# Not able to display random words in python

Tags: python, random, time

```
import random
from words import voc_list
import time
from plyer import notification

def get_word():
    word = random.choice(voc_list)
    return word.upper()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
    
        notification.notify(
        title = "Here is another vocablary word :-"
        The_word = random.choice(voc_list)
        Timeout = 8
        )
```

I am trying to make a vocabulary reminder that tells you a new word in every 2 hours. I made a list of words along with their meaning and trying to display any one randomly for which I have used from words import voc_list but why it is showing as invalid syntax here         The_word = random.choice(voc_list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing multiple parameters in the `notify` method and missing commas for the parameters.

```
import random
from words import voc_list
import time
from plyer import notification

def get_word():
    word = random.choice(voc_list)
    return word.upper()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
    
        notification.notify(
        title = "Here is another vocablary word :-",
        The_word = random.choice(voc_list),
        Timeout = 8
        )
```

If you are using your imported modules correctly, then this should work.

Answer (score 3):

Please have another look at the docs for the Pyler library: https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plyer.facades.Notification.notify.

The arguments `The_word` and `Timeout` are not valid arguments for `notify`. Also, you are missing commas in between the arguments to the `notify` function. Also, I suspect you probably wanted the word itself to be part of the title.

Try:

```
notification.notify(
    title=f"Here is another vocabulary word: {random.choice(voc_list)}",
    timeout=8
)
```

And please be mindful of indentation.